# Generate PDF in .Net core 2.0 using rdlc

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, asp.net-core-2.0

With .Net Core 2.0 not supporting Report Viewer, is there any other alternative way of doing this?

I found alanjuden's solution (https://alanjuden.com/2016/11/10/mvc-net-core-report-viewer/), but actually looking for official references.

We have migrated our project from .Net Framework 4.5.2 to .Net Core 2.0. However, stuck up with these reporting files as core 2.0 doesn't support.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49309797/rdlc-local-report-viewer-for-asp-net-core-and-angular2-0

Answer (score 5):

Look at this answer, it might help you.
[RDLC Local report viewer for ASP.NET Core and Angular(>2.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49309797/rdlc-local-report-viewer-for-asp-net-core-and-angular2-0)
It looks like Microsoft is working on it (or better spending on it, but no official packages seems to be available just yet).

Other references can be found here:
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/1528

Where they mention PDF libraries and export functionalities

Another library that might help you: https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNetCore.Reporting

Commercial solution: https://help.syncfusion.com/aspnet-core/reportviewer/getting-started

Other possible duplicates:

- [Rendering .rdlc reports with ASP .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54932390/rendering-rdlc-reports-with-asp-net-core)
- [Microsoft LocalReport (rdl) in ASP.NET Core MVC App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52513800/microsoft-localreport-rdl-in-asp-net-core-mvc-app)

Answer (score 1):

I found this package useful. I have successfully created a pdf using the RDLC using this library. I'm hoping to write a blog post on that soon. https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNetCore.Reporting

However there's a major issue in this library where when you have multiple files it doesn't work properly. It uses some internal caching so whatever the first requested rdlc file only will work.

Update:
I have written an article on how you can integrate this library to generate a pdf. Please check this link.
http://blog.geveo.com/IntegratingRDLCReportsToNetCoreProjects

Comment: I don't know how to use this library. Can you write some code?

Comment: I'm writing a blog post. Soon I will share the link with you.

Comment: @Sophairk pls find the link  http://blog.geveo.com/IntegratingRDLCReportsToNetCoreProjects