# How to consume rdl(SSRS) files from asp.net core application?

Tags: asp.net-core-2.2, rdl

I have created an rdl(SSRS)file. How can I consume the same from core controller and display it?

Somebody please help me to fix the same

Thanks
Krishnan

Comment: The only way to currently render client RDLC reports with .NET core is to use the paid [Syncfusion solution](https://help.syncfusion.com/aspnet-core/reportviewer/getting-started)Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54932390/rendering-rdlc-reports-with-asp-net-core